# taking max element(s)

Tags: sql

I have the following table :

```
     X     Y                  X --> Y   and X is a primary key 
    __________
    1     2323
    2     3122
    3     4343
    4     4343
    5     123
```

I want print out X according to max Y value .

output :

```
     X     Y
    __________
     3    4343
     4    4343
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: why is (x) 2 not listed on the output?

Comment: @johntotetwoo: Because it does not relate to a maximal value for `Y`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select X,Y from table where Y=(Select max(y) from table)
```

Edited (User wanted both X & Y in output)

Answer (score 0):

Typically it'd be simple:

```
SELECT MAX(`Y`) FROM `table`
```

It's a little more complex since you want to account for duplicate `Y` values and pull out *all* relevant rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `Y` = (SELECT MAX(`Y`) FROM `table`)
```

Hopefully this is fairly self-explanatory.